# Vertically centering element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dynamic, height, vertical-alignment

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

LI is (60px x 60px) but the images inside have different heights. I think they can be centered if the margin is set dynamically:

```
margin-top = height-of-li - height-of-img / 2
```

How do I do that with jQuery.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var image_height = $('li').find('img').height();
var padding = (60 - image_height) / 2;
$('li').find('img').css('margin-top', padding+'px');
```

Could this help?